# Cyclic Permutation (Check My Answer)

Tags: combinatorics

There are 5 boys and 3 girls be seated at a round table, how many ways they sit which **no** girls sitting side by side?

Using cyclic permutation, we have $3$ elements, i.e. $BGBGBG$, $G$, and $G$. So, counting the ways is
$$(3-1)!×3!×3!=2×6×6=72.$$

$3!\times3!$ is number of ways which boys and girl can change positions.

Is it right answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The answer is larger.
Let's get the boys seated first. This can be done in $4!$ ways. Now you have 5 possible positions to place the girls so that the above criteria is met. You can place 3 girls in those 5 places in $^5P_3$ ways.
Which leads to the final answer of $60*24 = 1440$.

You have 5 boys so one of those 3! should infact be 5!